# Why does my datatype of a particular column dont change(from character to date) even after i tried to use CASt(),STR_to_date()

Tags: mysql

Why does my datatype of a particular column don't change(from character to date) even after I tried to use `CASt()`, `STR_to_date()`.

I also tried changing the design data type and it still didn't work.

Comment: Table datatype can only be changed with an ALTER statement. STR_TO_DATE will return null if the function cannot convert the string with the parameters you gave it. DO you have an example of your problem?

Comment: my column name is iommej and my db is inv_source. Even i tried using alter table but still it gives me conversion error - ALTER TABLE inv_source ALTER Column s_iommej date

Comment: @P.Salmon can you please give me your email id so that i can shoot my questions to you

Comment: I guess you need to fix your data before atempting ALTER.

Comment: Yes @P.Salmon, do you mind sharing your email id

Comment: do you mind sharing your email id – YES I do..